# Meaning of これでもかという forms

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions

Sorry to ask a vague question, but I hope someone could explain what these following expression amount to.

> これでもかって
>
> これでもかってほど
>
> これでもかってぐらいに

I thought I would figure this out eventually but well I don't there is only about a dozen sources on this expression each never reaffirming.

*Even with this, to this degree*, was my best guess. What I have read seem to suggest that it highlights the degree or choice of action as excessive but I don't even know anymore. I hope someone will kindly teach me how to understand this.

Here are some samples from Youtube titles,

**こぼれいくらがたまらない！これでもかって程の大粒いくら丼！**

**ウルトラマンFE3 これでもかというぐらいに撃つ**

**これでもかってくらいのドロップキック！**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「これでもか」 is an expression used rather heavily in mostly informal speech.

I would suggest that you think of it as an **embedded question** within a longer sentence.  The 「か」 is indeed a question marker.  This should also explain why the quotative particle 「と」 or 「って」 will always follow.

「これでも」, by itself, means "even (with) this (amount/degree)."

So, what is the question implied by 「これでもか」?  It should generally be along the lines of:

> "Isn't this enough?"
>
> "Aren't you satisfied with this amount/degree/frequency?"
>
> "Wouldn't you call this an onslaught?"

Thus, by adding 「ってほど」、「ってぐらいに」, 「というほど」, etc. to 「これでもか」, you are essentially saying:

> "as if to say 'Isn't this enough?'"

That is why I had to mention the quotative particles that go with the expression in question.  The heavy use of embedded questions is a feature of our language, which is why we use 「という」、「っていう」、「っつう」、「っちゅう」, etc. all day everyday.  We love to quote things without having Japanese-learners even notice it.  To prove it, SE is full of questions about this.

> こぼれいくらがたまらない！これでもかって程の大粒いくら丼！

describes the surprisingly large amount of salmon roe poured on the rice.  "as if to say 'Aren't you satisfied with ***this*** amount of salmon roe?'"

> ウルトラマンFE3 これでもかというぐらいに撃つ

expresses the intensity of his attack.  "as if to say 'Isn't this enough shooting?'"

> これでもかってくらいのドロップキック！

describes the strength or the unexpectedly large number of the kicks.  Which one it refers to, we do not know without further context.