What does っつぅ mean?
example sentences (from wind breaker anime):
食べるものっつぅよりこうやってみんなでワイワイしながら食べることが好きなんだよ
俺がてっぺんだっつぅこととなんの関係もない
simple sentences despite the fact I've never seen っつぅbefore. It feels similar to って but its different. Is it some sort of slang/dialect variant of something?

Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/77691/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1253/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72704/9831

This is a slangy contraction of という, so this just corresponds to というより.

jogloran さん、ログインし忘れて２つアカウント作っちゃいました？　merge 可能ですけどどうされます？

@chocolate あれ、間違って別垢作っちゃいましたね。mergeできればお願いします。

@jogloran コミュニティチームにマージ依頼を申請してみました。処理に数日かかるかもですが。
